# How can I initiate drawing on my Google Map?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I found this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_picker

I looked through his code and tried figuring out how he initiates drawing. What he accomplishes is far more complicated than I need, and I can't figure out the first step of what he did. I also don't want to take the guy's code. Can anyone explain how to accomplish this?

I just want to be able to circle objects on my map. There seems to be a polyline solution but it's just straight lines from a list of coordinates, not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: using the stack may be???

Comment: I'd need the drawing added to my map though. Not just on top of my current view. My map is already stacked. Unless stack means something else here, I don't think this would work.

Comment: this can be achieved solely using flutter with map, i don't know what he's doing, but flutter google map lets convert the local widget coordinate to real world coordinate, I've used it put a marker on the map where the user touches, drawing just involves multiple touch points!!

Comment: I have something like that implemented for breadcrumbs: a timer dropping 1 marker every 3 seconds. Any idea how to freeze the map and allow an onpressed-> drop numerous markers event? I think this may be laggy...

Answer (score 1):

A Stack widget with GoogleMap and CustomPaint will let you draw anything you want on top of the map.

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      _position == null
          ? Text('Waiting for location . .')
          : GoogleMap(
              liteModeEnabled: false,
              compassEnabled: true,
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude),
                zoom: 17,
                tilt: 0,
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _mapController = controller;
                // trigger initial update and paint of landmarks
                _updateLandmarks();
              },
              onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
                _updateLandmarks();
              },
            ),
      CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: MapPainter(_landmarksMap),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

You have to convert map coordinates to device screen coordinates. Google has a cookbook on how to do that except it does not work in Flutter since the map plugin does not expose the complete API. But there is a way to do it of course.

```
    void _updateLandmarks() async {

  double dpi = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
  LatLngBounds bounds = await _mapController.getVisibleRegion();
  ScreenCoordinate topRight = await _mapController.getScreenCoordinate(bounds.northeast);
  ScreenCoordinate bottomLeft = await _mapController.getScreenCoordinate(bounds.southwest);

  _landmarksMap.values.forEach((element) async {
    ScreenCoordinate sc = await _mapController.getScreenCoordinate(LatLng(element.pos.latitude, element.pos.longitude));
    element.screenPoint.x = ((sc.x - bottomLeft.x) / dpi).floor();
    element.screenPoint.y = ((sc.y - topRight.y) / dpi).floor();
  });

  setState(() {});
}
```

You can read here for more details: https://aperico.com/google-maps-with-custom-paint-in-flutter/

Comment: adding these should work as intended?